# PyTorch, simple char level RNN, can't overfit one example

Tags: machine-learning, char, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, pytorch

I'm new to the PyTorch framework (coming from Theano and Tensorflow mainly):
I've followed the introduction tutorial and read the *Classifying Names with a Character-Level RNN* one.
I now try to adapt it to a char level LSTM model in order to gain some practical experience with the framework. 
Basically I feed in the model sequences of char indices and give as target to the model the same sequence but shifted by one in the future.
However I can't overfit a simple training example and I don't see what I did wrong.
If someone can spot my mistake it would be very helpful.
Here is my code:

```
class LSTMTxtGen(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, hidden_dim, n_layer, vocab_size):
    super(LSTMTxtGen, self).__init__()
    self.n_layer = n_layer
    self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
    self.vocab_size = vocab_size

    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(vocab_size, hidden_dim, n_layer, batch_first=True)

    # The linear layer that maps from hidden state space to tag space
    #self.hidden = self.init_hidden()

def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
    # Before we've done anything, we dont have any hidden state.
    # Refer to the Pytorch documentation to see exactly
    # why they have this dimensionality.
    # The axes semantics are (num_layers, minibatch_size, hidden_dim)
    return (autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(self.n_layer, batch_size, 
                                          self.hidden_dim)),
            autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(self.n_layer, batch_size, 
                                          self.hidden_dim)))

def forward(self, seqs):
    self.hidden = self.init_hidden(seqs.size()[0])
    lstm_out, self.hidden = self.lstm(seqs, self.hidden)
    lstm_out = lstm_out.contiguous().view(-1, self.hidden_dim)
    lstm_out = nn.Linear(lstm_out.size(1), self.vocab_size)(lstm_out)
    return lstm_out

model = LSTMTxtGen (
hidden_dim = 50,
n_layer = 3,
vocab_size = 44,
)

print(Model)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adamax(model.parameters())

G = Data.batch_generator(5,100)
batch_per_epoch, to_idx, to_char = next(G)
X, Y = next(G)
for epoch in range(10):
    losses = []
    for batch_count in range(batch_per_epoch):
        model.zero_grad()

        #mode.hidden = model.init_hidden()

        #X, Y = next(G)
        X = autograd.Variable(torch.from_numpy(X))
        Y = autograd.Variable(torch.from_numpy(Y))

       preds = model(X)

       loss = criterion(preds.view(-1, model.vocab_size), Y.view(-1))
       loss.backward()
       optimizer.step()
       losses.append(loss)

       if (batch_count % 20 == 0):
           print('Loss: ', losses[-1])
```